# One column calculate multiple output

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have show the total product sale on the basis YTD (Year to Date), QTD(Quarter to Date) and MTD (Month to Date). The thing is I have to show only one from those. Only one output can be seen on the basis of selection i.e. like we have radio buttons to select one from many. Here also a input is given to select and on the basis of that input the output is generated. The input can be any YTD,QTD or MTD. The output is generated on the basis of input. I don't how to calculate a column output where the input can be vary.
I have a Product Table-

```
Product_ID       Product_name          Price
1                  Mobile               200
2                   T.V.                400
3                  Mixer                300
```

I have a Sales table like this-

```
Product_ID          Sales_Date         Quantity
1                   01-01-2015            30
2                   03-01-2015            40
3                   06-02-2015            10
1                   22-03-2015            30
2                   09-04-2015            10
3                   21-05-2015            40
1                   04-06-2015            40
2                   29-07-2015            30
1                   31-08-2015            30
3                   14-09-2015            30
```

And my ouput column contains 3 columns that are-
`Product_id, Product_Name and Total_Amount`.
 The column Total_Amount(quantity*price) have to calculate sale on the basis of input given by user i.e.,

```
IF it is YTD then it should calculate the total sale from Starting Date of Year ( 01-01-2015) to the current_date(sysdate),

IF it is QTD then in which quarter the current date is falling i.e if current month is september then from 1 July to current_date(sysdate),

IF it is MTD then in which month the current date is falling to the current_date(sysdate).
```

Can anyone help. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- step 1
create or replace view my_admin
as
select 'YTD' element, product_id,  sum(quantity) sum_quantity   
from sales
where Sales_date  between trunc(sysdate,'Y') and sysdate
group by product_id 
union
select 'QTD', product_id, sum(quantity) sum_quantity  
from sales
where Sales_date  between trunc(sysdate,'Q') and sysdate
group by product_id
union
select 'MTD', product_id, sum(quantity) sum_quantity  
from sales
where Sales_date  between trunc(sysdate,'MM') and sysdate
group by product_id



-- step 2
select element, p.product_name,  (sum_quantity * p.PRICE) agregate
from my_admin a
inner join products p  on a.product_id = p.product_id  
where element = (:input)
```

Comment: The query does not ask which product_id should be calculated :( its just calculate

Comment: sorry, I forgot to join to product; the script has been altered, plus a multiply with price has been added

Answer (score 0):

My presumption is that you have 3 radio buttons(variables :YTD,:QTD,:MTD in my example) where just one value at a time can be picked by the user the rest will be null.

You can use a something like this to get what you want:

```
select SUM(a.QTY*B.PRICE) from PRODUCTS a
inner join SALES B on a.PRODUCT_ID=B.PRODUCT_ID
where 
(:YTD is null or B.SALES_DATE between '01-JAN-15' and sysdate)
and
(:QTD is null or TO_CHAR(B.SALES_DATE, 'YYYY-Q')=TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-Q'))
and
(:MTD is null or TO_CHAR(B.SALES_DATE, 'MM')=TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM'));
```

You can test it here **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7c33/4)**

Comment: your query is giving the same result for all 3 :( and also my qty is contained in sale table and price is contained in product table

Comment: Please create the tables and data on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so i can correct the script.

Comment: sorry man..I tried but I cant create it is always throwing error I don't know why

Comment: I didn't got any errors. You can test it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7c33/4)

Comment: how it is calculating for which product it should give qtd, ytd or mtd...it is giving the resultant of all